# Update to latest Squish Version 6.4.2

Tags: squish

I am currently using squish version : 6.4.1 with a valid license.
how do i update to latest version? 
@frog.ca do you have any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

To move to a new Squish version download its installer and install into a new folder. Keeping the existing Squish installations is just fine. Thoroughly check the new Squish installation to ensure it works as required - as should be done for new versions of any software.